# Reconstructing dataframes with map_dfr() in R

Tags: r, purrr

I am having the toy `iris` dataset split into 3 parts with respect to the classes they have.

```
setosa <- read_csv("iris-setosa.csv") %>%
  mutate(Species = "setosa")
versicolor <- read_csv("iris-versicolor.csv") %>%
  mutate(Species = "versicolor")
virginica <- read_csv("iris-virginica.csv") %>%
  mutate(Species = "virginica")
df_iris <- bind_rows(setosa, versicolor, virginica)
df_iris
```

I want to recreate this df using `map_dfr()` as I read it can be done in a much simpler way. I have tried the following but not completely able to write it.

```
species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
map_dfr(species, ~ df_iris)
```

Comment: From the character vector, `species` I wish to create.

Comment: I just edited my post. I needed it like that.

Comment: Please note that when you used the earlier code with linear model, it is a completely differtent task and you are not building any model (based on the description)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that I did not completely understand the intention of that now I did. Also, can you comment on the `get` variable in your first pipeline?

Comment: I added some description

Comment: Yeah, it is now completely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to recreate the 'df_iris' with `map` based on object names as string, use `get` within the loop

```
df_iris2 <- map_dfr(species, get)
```

`get` is a `base R` function that returns or gets the object value from the global environment based on the object name as a string

---

Or with `bind_rows`

```
df_iris3 <- bind_rows(mget(species))
```

Comment: Can you briefly comment about the `'iv'` variable, I\m not able to connect with the syntax? I am getting an error for `iv` : `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'iv' not found`

Comment: @RanjiRaj I am also not sure.  In your syntax, there is `iv` and I thought you created that

Comment: @RanjiRaj what is this `lm(.x ~ iv)` in your code

Comment: To be honest I came from your post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403043/purrrmap-dfr-binds-by-columns-not-row-as-expected , but has difficulty in understanding the logic.

Comment: @RanjiRaj in that post, there is an independent variable named 'iv'.  But, in your case, I am not sure what you want as formula

Comment: I just want to simplify the first code chunk that I posted using `map_dfr()`. I learn that `lm` is kind of a linear model and what goes inside is a formula. So I tried creating a vector of classes so that I go as the value for classes.

Comment: @RanjiRaj The issue with your code is that it is not giving any indication about what you want to do.  What is your independent variable used in the `lm`